# .net odata.metadata not showing for a member type

Tags: json, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have a type with a member that is not a simple type. For example,

```
class Person
{
   int a;
   Pmetadata personInfo;
}
```

Type **Person** is being returned as a response in an **ODataController**(WebAPI Framework). In the response json returned from the controller, the root object has an **'odata.metadata'** decoration, but the object personInfo doesn't have the **'odata.metadata'** decoration.
I tried adding type **Pmetadata** to the EntityModel using a call as follows,

```
odatamodelbuilder.EntitySet<Pmetadata>("PersonMetadata");
```

but it hasn't helped.

What causes the **odata.metadata** to appear?

Answer (score 0):

Add $format to your request URL may resolve your problem:

```
GET ~/Products?$format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata
```

There is diff between these two requests, please have a try:

1. http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=application/json;odata=nometadata
2. http://services.odata.org/v3/OData/OData.svc/Products?$format=application/json;odata=fullmetadata

Comment: If Pmetadata is added as an entity type, then $expand is needed to display it: ~/Persons?$expand=personInfo